# How to do nested find in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a user model which has todolists field, in the todolists field I want to get the specific todolist by id. my query is like this:

```
 User.find({_id: user._id, _creator: user, todoList: todoList._id}, 'todoLists') // how do I query for todoList id here? I used _creator this on populate query.
```

Can I also do a search on a Usermodel field like this?

```
User.todoLists.find({todoList: todoList._id})
```

I haven't tested this yet because I am still modifying my Graphql schema and I am new in mongoose.I would really appreciate Links and suggestions. Help?

Comment: Can you add the user schema definition to your question?

Comment: no, you can't. the above query will return you a user object. if you want to get the todolist itself, you have to use the aggregation framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your models looks like this:

```
const todoListSchema = new Schema({
    item: { type: String },
}, { collection: 'todolist' });

const userSchema = new Schema({
    todoList: [todoListSchema],
}, { collection: 'user' });

mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
mongoose.model('todoList', todoListSchema);
```

Now you have multiple ways to do that:

**1. Using the array filter() method**
[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

```
User.findById(_id, (err, user) => {
    const todoList = user.todoList.filter(id => id.equals(tdlId));
    //your code..
})
```

**2. Using mongoose id() method**
[reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

```
User.findById(_id, (err, user) => {
        const todoList = user.todoList.id(tdlId);
        //your code..
    })
```

**3. Using mongoose aggregate**
[reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

```
User.aggregate(
        { $match: { _id: userId} },
        { $unwind: '$todoList' },
        { $match: { todoList: tdlId } },
        { $project: { todoList: 1 } }
    ).then((user, err) => {
         //your code..
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was only reading mongoose docs. mongodb docs helped a lot. I wanted to do the work on mongoose and not perform any js. thanks

Comment: I am using number 2 because of specificty. But I would appreciate if you let me know what youre using and suggestion.

Comment: I'm using the aggregate framework. I geuss you can acheive your goal with all of the options above. Using aggregate framework is easier for me and more intuitive.

Comment: With 1 or 2 it easier to manipulate the data with a programming languages such as js.